# Javascript - change css of div to make visible?

Tags: javascript, css

Using CSS I have set a DIV called 'tidy' to invisible and width 0px.

```
<div id='tidy'>Test div I am hidden</div>
```

I am trying to use just javascript to keep the page light, so cannot use jquery.

How can I make a link that when clicked will make the div visible again and set width to xxxpx?

Comment: instead if jquery, you may consider using http://zeptojs.com/ to simplify your javascript work and still have a pretty lightweight javascript

Comment: Why is this -2?  is it impossible to do with just javascript?

Comment: How did you set it not visible via css? Because that's exactly the property you need to modify via Javascript.

Comment: #tidy{visibility:hidden and width:0px;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fcQGh/)

```
function makevisible() {
     var tidy = document.getElementById("tidy");
     tidy.style.display= 'block';
     tidy.style.width = '100px';    
}  ​
```

Comment: I changed it to display:none after seeing other answers but you included jsfiddle which I used.  So tick.

Answer (score 3):

Use the display style for hide and doesn't occupied space in page:

```
var node = document.getElementById("tidy");

function hideTidy() {
    node.style.display = "none";
}

function showTidy() {
    node.style.display = "";
}
```

Add simple toggle:

```
var tidyVisible = true;

function toggleTidy() {
    (tidyVisible ? hideTidy : showTidy)();
    tidyVisible = !tidyVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

let's imagine you have link like this:

```
<a href="#" id="tidy_toggle">click to display hidden element</a>
```

you can use it like this:

```
var toggler = document.getElementById('tidy_toggle');
var tidy = document.getElementById('tidy');
toggler.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    tidy.style.display = 'block';
    tidy.style.width = 'xxxpx';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('tidy').style.visibility = 'visible';
```